# Pass any function regardless of its parameters

Tags: c#, .net

Assuming that I have the following three methods

```
void Execute(<What to put here?> method)
{
    method();
}

void Function1(string a) { ... }
void Function2(int a) { ... }
```

how can I pass the functions `Function1` and `Function2` **with designated parameters** to the `Execute` method?

e.g. like this

```
Execute(Function1("Foo"));
```

but above example is *calling* the function, I want it to be called only in the `Execute` method.

---

I hope it got clear, if it doesn't, I am looking for a way just like this:

```
void Execute(Action method)
{
    method();
}

void Function3() { ... }
```

which can then be called like this:

```
Execute(Function3);
```

so that `Function3` is called in the `Execute` method, not when invoking the `Execute` method.
I want to be able to do the same thing, but **pass specific parameters to the `Function3` method** that should be used when it is invoked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply make a lambda out of it:

```
Execute(() => Function1("Foo"));
```

Comment: yeah, this is the only good way to do this; the alternative is `object[]` and `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` - so by the time you've paid for the `object[]`, a capture context (if one is even needed - it isn't needed in your example) is fine

Comment: @PatrickHofman thank you very much, this is embarrassing. I should have come up with that too, but I was too fixated on `Action` and delegates. @MarcGravell thank you too, I will go the easier way with the lambda though. I can accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @HansW just for info: this is an example of "partial application"